# Looping through properties of object in an array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to loop and print the properties of the array of objects (only one time)

Html

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in items">{{key}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Script

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{'name':10, 'phone':11},{'name':10, 'phone':11}];
}
```

The desired effect would be:

name

phone

It works only if I have one object and not an array of objects

Here is a link to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3vzd732s/2/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you have given in the question seems to run correctly. In the fiddle istead of {{key}} you have given {{name}}.

If you know that it is going to be an array, how about pointing to the first element in the array?

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in items[0]">{{key}}</li>
```

Comment: It does run correctly when I have one object, but the issue is when I have an array and I want to read the properties names of the first element for instance. Try with my array above.

Comment: How about this?<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in items[0]">{{key}}</li>

Answer (score 1):

Updated solution after question clarification:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
            <p ng-repeat="(key, value) in item">{{key}} {{value}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You forgot to wrap your items in Array in your fiddle example, here is an updated one:

http://jsfiddle.net/3vzd732s/5/

Comment: But the idea is to build the labels dynamically. I am not suppose to know what the properties are.

Comment: so, you have to use second `ng-repeat` inside to achieve this

Comment: One to loop the  array to extract the first object, then one for the element to loop through it's properties?

Comment: yep, that's exactly what we did.

Comment: and `track by $index` is recommended to avoid dupes in Array https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes

Comment: I'll give this as good answer even if both were correct, simply for being first. Thanks it works now.

Comment: @Magini Remmeber to use 1.2.0 because 1.0.3 doesn't have track by feature

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <p ng-repeat="(key,value) in item">
            {{key}} {{value}}

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9n3z74r/)

**UPDATE** Change the answer for multiple objects.

Comment: And one thing you are using angular version 1.0.3 and ng-repeat has track by feature enable from 1.2.0

Comment: Same issue. Look at my comment to paje007, try with my array above.

Comment: Close thanks, But one time only! it is like printing the labels for a table header

Comment: Oops sorry miss the <p > tag ending